# How do I call to a line in some data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgSKH.jpg).

I need to call the first and second column (time and ml).

I have imported everything relevant.

This is the part of the code that I am screwing up with:

```
 time = []
 d180= []

 a = np.arange(0.0, 5320.0, 1.0)
 b = np.array(a, dtype=float)


 file = open(filename)

 for line in file:
  for i in a:
     if line[0] == 'P':
         False
     elif line[0] == 'T':
         False
     else:

         fields = (line.strip()).split('\t')
         time.append(fields[0])
         d180.append(fields[1])


file.close()     


time = np.array(time, dtype=float)
d180 = np.array(benthic, dtype=float)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, d180)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('ml')
plt.show()
```

Right now I am getting an index error "list out of range" for d180.append(fields[1]).

I should mention the numpy array, b, is left over from a previous attempt at trying something like this:

```
for i in len(b):
  for line in file:
      if float(line[0]) == b[i]
          fields = (line.strip()).split('\t')
          time.append(fields[0])
          d180.append(fields[1])
```

But that didn't work for probably a few reasons, primarily because of the inability to convert 'P' or 'T' to a float.

Finally, it may be relevant that the data file is a .txt file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Most important attempt to debug this on your own first: what is the value of `fields` that you believe has two elements, but causes the error?

Comment: Also, remove the non-functional parts of your posting.  For instance, instead of evaluating `False` and discarding the result, just use `pass`.  Better yet, change your test logic to "accept" only those lines you want to process.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [`read_table` from Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html), you'd do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(
  filename, skiprows=6,
  names=['time', 'd180', 'stderr'],
)

plt.plot(df['time'], df['d180'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just saw it: the input you failed to post in the question has a blank line.  When you process the blank with this code:

```
     fields = (line.strip()).split('\t')
     time.append(fields[0])
     d180.append(fields[1])
```

`fields` will have 0 or 1 element, depending on the actual characters in the "blankness".